# Does an Audi A3 8P have two front airbag sensors or one?

Tags: vw, audi, supplemental-restraint-system

I'm getting the pieces for missing front airbag sensors (the radiator support was replaced) for an Audi A3 2011 8P.

My usual goto spot for VAG part diagrams [here](http://www.oemepc.com/audi/part_single/catalog/au/markt/CA/modell/A3/year/2013/drive_standart/646/hg_ug/959/subcategory/959030/part_id/0/lang/e) shows a diagram with one sensor - part number 8J0959651. However running VCDS to look at the airbag codes, VCDS reports an open circuit error for the passenger-side and the drivers-side. Looking at the radiator support, there is a mounting spot for a sensor on each side. I suspect the wiring harness was damaged on one side so there's no evident plug (at least to me). The passenger side has a yellow plug that seems to be the correct connector.

So I want to determine whether I need one or two of these sensors. I don't plan on touching anything airbag related (aware of the dangers). I just want to give the right parts to an knowledegable automotive electrician who can do the required repairs.